# What is the best way to update the accessToken in the app with the new accessToken?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, jwt

### Before getting to the actual question

Alright I have created my own authentication system that I am going to use on my API.

**Simple explanation:**
On `/signup` the user types in username, password etc... the API grants the user with `tokens` which are stored in the user document in the database. The API also returns with a response body with the new `refreshToken` and `accessToken`, my thought here is so the app easily can store the tokens on the phone for later calls to the API.

`/login` is pretty much the same thing except you only provide username and password.

One of the routes in the API is the `/article` which you can `GET` & `POST`.

Now if you try to for example `GET` the `/article` and your `accessToken` is expired the API will automatically call `/token` which requires the `refreshToken` in the header, the `/token` will then grant you a new `accessToken` and request the same route you were trying to get (in this case `/article`) with the new `accessToken` in the header.

**The question**:
What is the best way to update the `accessToken` in the app with the **new** `accessToken`?

```
router
  .route('/article')
    .get(
      AuthenticateController.authenticate,
      NewsController.getAllArticles,
      AuthenticateController.sendAuthorize
);
```

This is how I do it now, `AuthenticateController.authenticate` authenticates the accessToken and checks if it is expired and all that then calls `next()`.

The `NewsController.getAllArticles` gets all the articles and also calls `next()` so the `AuthenticateController.sendAuthorize` can run and return the new `accessToken` in the response header when a new one is granted (I thought this would make it easier to obatin the new token in the app). This is where my question comes in because I can't call `next()` on every route because on some routes the main function already returns a response and that means that `next()` cannot be called which means `AuthenticateController.sendAuthorize` will never run. I want the `AuthenticateController.authenticate` to be the only middleware required to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting until the last route to send the new token, you should move the `sendAuthorize` middleware above the route's main response (or combine it with `authenticate`), and instead send a `401 Unauthorized` response with the new token. Then, update the token on the client and resend the request.

It seems like a silly practice to send a valid response with an invalid `accessToken` anyway. You're going to want to invalidate tokens eventually (I.e on log out or password change), and you don't want users to be able to make unauthenticated requests.

Comment: Thanks this helped me get what I wanted!